# Mock a parent class in a child class with Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, inheritance, mockito

I have a question about Mockito with Java and I need your help:
I have a class A that have an implementation and a class B with its implementation...and in the final class C I would like to mock the main class A. Is it possible??
The draw would be like this:

```
 Class A ----> Class B ---> Class C
```

and I want to mock A inside C (obiously there is inheritance between A and B, and between B and C). Either A and B and C are DAO classes with their own implementation classes.

How can I do this? How can I mock A inside C implementation class with Mockito?

Thanks for your support and kind regards

Answer (score 1):

if `A` extends `B` and you want to test `A` mocking `B` methods, you can use a [spy](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg-history/be6d53f62790ac7c9cf07c32485343ce94e1b563/1.9.5/org/mockito/Spy.html) of `A` and mock `B` methods:

```
final A spy = Mockito.spy(yourInstanceOfA);
Mockito.doReturn(something).when(spy).methodOfB();

spy.methodOfA();
// add some assertions
```

Answer (score 0):

If C is merely the extensible last class in your hierarchy, and not `final`, you could partially mock C:

```
/**
 * Tests C.foo(), which calls method bar() defined in A.
 */
@Test public void testFoo() {
  // Spy on the system under test. This is unusal, but necessary here.
  C c = Mockito.spy(new C());

  // This ensures c.bar is never actually called, as opposed to Mockito.when().
  Mockito.doReturn("quux").when(c).bar();

  assertEquals("[quux]", c.foo());
}
```

If C is `final`, though, you may have to test it as an entire unit and not merely its upgrades over B.

```
@RunWith(JUnit4.class) public class CTest extends BTest {
  @Override protected B createB() {
    return new C();
  }

  @Test public void testCSpecificBehavior() { /* ... */ }
}
```

If you have the option in the future, you may consider [favoring composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance), as it gives you a few more options in testing.